# Java nested generics with raw types return type inference

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, return-type, nested-generics

```java
public class Main {
    List<List<Integer>> f0() {
        return List.of(List.of(1L));
    }
    List<List<Integer>> f1() {
        return List.of((List) List.of(1L));
    }
    List<List<Integer>> f2() {
        var r = List.of((List) List.of(1L));
        return r;
    }
    List<List<Integer>> f3() {
        return List.of((List) List.of(1L), List.of(1L));
    }
    List<List<Integer>> f4() {
        return List.of((List) List.of(1L), (List) List.of(1L));
    }
}
```

In the code above, `f1` and `f4` compile while `f0`, `f2` and `f3` do not.
I can see why `f0` doesn't compile: It needs `List<List<Integer>>` but it sees `List<List<Long>>`. But I have no idea why others behave the way they do.

**f2:**

```
incompatible types: List<List> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>
```

**f3:**

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
                return List.of((List) List.of(1L), List.of(1L));
                              ^
    equality constraints: Integer
    lower bounds: Long
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>of(E)
```

In each function, what exactly is the type of the expression being returned? Why does Java behave like this? And what is happening according to the JLS? I'm using Java 17 if it's important.

Comment: What do you not understand from the message from the compiler ? I think the compiler errors are pretty clear on what is expected

Comment: For example: Why does f1 compile but f2 does not? It's the same expression. How is returning it different from using it elsewhere? Or how does java know when to let go of the type inference like in f4? It could've done that in f3 as well. If I explicitly use raw type for a parameter, does java exclude it from type inference? So in this case I have to explicitly cast every parameter to raw type? Where is this mentioned in the JLS?

Comment: Because there are certain limitations to type inference in Java and complicated rules to make raw types work for backward compatibility. With combinations like this it's hard to know exactly why, you'd have to dig into the exact rules which you can find in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). (In real code, [don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)).

Comment: Actually that's my question. I could dig into the rules but it would take much time. I thought maybe someone already knows or at least is familiar with JLS more than I am that would do this.

Comment: For example, why `f2` does not compile is because the scope of type inference is limited. To determine what the type of `r` must be, the compiler is only going to look at the type of the expression after the `=`; it's not going to infer that because of `return r;` it should look at the return type of the method.

Comment: I see. But then why `List<List>` is incompatible with `List<List<Integer>>`? I thought raw types could be used instead of the generic one. For example you can return `Class` type when `Class<A>` is the return type of the function (with warning of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `f2` and `f0` is that `List.of` is not in an assignment context in `f2`, [§14.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1):

> If the LocalVariableType is `var`, then let `T` be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context ...

Hence, the call is not a poly expression. It doesn't satisfy the requirements for being a poly expression in [§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12):

> A method invocation expression is a poly expression if all of the following are true:
>
> - The invocation appears in an assignment context or an invocation context
> - ...

This means that type inference no longer takes into account the target type ([§15.12.2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6)).

> If the chosen method is generic and the method invocation does not provide explicit type arguments, the invocation type is inferred as specified in §18.5.2.
>
> In this case, if the method invocation expression is a poly expression, then its compatibility with a target type is as determined by [§18.5.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.1).

The entirety of §18.5.2.1, which would have added some constraint about `Integer`, is skipped.

If you put `List.of` in a return statement, however, it *is* in an assignment context ([§14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)):

> It is a compile-time error if the return target of a return statement with value Expression is a method with declared return type `T`, and the type of Expression is not assignable compatible (§5.2) with T.

(§5.2 is the section for assignment contexts)

More informally, Java doesn't look at *all* the places where `r` is used to infer the type parameter of `List.of`. It only looks at the call `List.of((List) List.of(1L))`. It is assigned to a `var`, so type inference results in `List<List>`. Type inference has no reason to randomly add a `<Integer>` in there.

`List<List>` is not compatible with `List<List<Integer>>`, because [generics are by default invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5133585). For how exactly this is specified, see [§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6). Try showing that `List<List>` is not a subtype of `List<List<Integer>>`.

---

For `f3`, there are conflicting constraints. I'll use `E` to refer to the type parameter of the outer `List.of` call, and `E1` and `E2` to refer to the type parameters of the first and second inner `List.of` call.

Because the outer `List.of` is in a return statement, §18.5.2.1 applies, and `E` gets a lower bound of `List<Integer>`.

`E1` is inferred to have a lower bound of `Long`, then §18.5.2.1 applies, and the target type is raw `List`, the type you are casting to. Nothing is wrong with that and we carry on.

The raw `List` in the first argument gives an upper bound of `List` for `E`. That's fine - no conflicts here.

In `f4`, the same thing happens with the second argument and `E2`, so there is no problem.

In `f3`, §18.5.2.1 applies when inferring `E2`, the target type is `List<Integer>`, because of the constraint on `E`. This adds an equality constraint to `E2`. The argument `1L` also adds a lower bound of `Long` to `E2`.

That's where the conflict is. There is no type that satisfies both `== Integer` and `>= Long`.

Comment: So in `f1` and `f4`, type of the expression becomes `List`. How is `List` returned as `List<List<Integer>>`? `List` obviously *is not* `List<List<Integer>>` (violates Liskov's rule). Does returning raw type turn off type-safety checking? If so, then why `List<List>>` is not compatible to `List<List<Integer>>` in the first part?

Comment: @ParSal in `f1`, only the inner expression (`(List) List.of(1L)`) becomes `List`. The outer expression still is a poly expression (`return List.of(…)`). So the expression’s type is `List<List<Integer>>` but the argument must be assignable to `List<Integer>`. So `List` is assigned to `List<Integer>` which is valid but produces an “unchecked” warning.

Comment: @ParSal In `f1` and `f4`, the type of the whole expression after `return` is not `List`. It's `List<List<Integer>>`, because type inference figured out that you mean `List.<List<Integer>>of(...)`. And `List` *is* compatible with `List<List<Integer>>` because raw types and their parameterised counterparts are subtypes of each other. This indeed is not safe, but that's how Java's generics work, in order to be backwards compatible. `List<List>` and `List<List<Integer>>` are different. They are both not raw types. `List<List>` is parameterised, it just so happens that the type parameter is raw.

Comment: @ParSal Although `List` is compatible with `List<Integer>`, `List<List>` is not compatible with `List<List<Integer>>` because generics are *invariant* by default. See §4.10 for the sub typing rules. There's no subtyping relation between `List<List>` and `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: Thanks! In `f3` and `f4`, what happens to `E1` when target type is raw `List`?

Comment: @ParSal The raw `List` target type does not add constraints to `E1`. `E1` only has the lower bound of `Long`.